# How to test function enside a Angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I tried test a function enside a controller in angularjs, but always fail.

this is for angularjs project

//controller---

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('My_module').controller('my_controller', function (
 $scope, $route, $timeout, $routeParams) {

   function first_function(data) {
     return and_array;
   }

   function second_function() {
     return and_obj;
   }
 }
```

//-----Spec----

```
'use strict';

 describe('My tests specs', function () {
  var route;
  var scope;

  var my_controller;
  beforeEach(function () {
    controller();
  });

  describe('first test', function(){
  it('test functions', fucntion(){
   expect(my_controller_Mock.first_function).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  });

  function controller() {inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, 
     $route) {
     route = $route;
     scope = $rootScope.$new();

  //--i tried these
   my_controller_Mock = jasmine.createSpyObj('my_controller', 
   ['first_function'])

  $controller('my_controller', {
    $scope: scope,
    $route: route,
    my_controller: my_controller_Mock
  });
 }
```

jasmine Error: Expected spy my_controller.first_function to have been called

Comment: You are never calling your function `controller()`.

Comment: Sorry now add de call to controller. same error

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're never calling `first_function`, so jasmine is correct that's it's not being called.